# Plugin reload doesn't remove ToolButton from MenuBar

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I have this in my `initGui()` Function:

```py
        self.add_action(
            icon_path,
            text=self.tr(u'ReKoTi Plugin'),
            callback=self.run,
            parent=self.iface.mainWindow())
        self.toolBar = self.iface.addToolBar("MY TOOLBAR tools")
        self.action = QAction(QIcon(icon_path), 'Validate Layers', self.iface.mainWindow())
        self.action.triggered.connect(self.validate_layers)
        self.iface.addPluginToMenu('&ReKoTi Plugin', self.action)
        self.iface.addToolBarIcon(self.action)

        self.toolBar = self.iface.mainWindow().findChild( QToolBar, u'ReKoTi Plugin' )
        if not self.toolBar:
            self.toolBar = self.iface.addToolBar( u'ReKoTi Plugin' )
            self.toolBar.setObjectName( u'ReKoTi Plugin' )
        
        self.popupMenu = QMenu(self.iface.mainWindow())
        self.actionMass = QAction("Mass", checkable=True)
        self.popupMenu.addAction(self.actionMass)
        self.toolButton = QToolButton(text="Calculations")

        self.toolButton.setMenu(self.popupMenu)
        self.toolButton.setPopupMode(QToolButton.InstantPopup)
        self.iface.addToolBarWidget(self.toolButton)
```

And this is my `unload()` Function:

```py
       for action in self.actions:
            self.iface.removePluginMenu(
                self.tr(u'&ReKoTi Plugin'),
                action)
            self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(action)
        # remove the toolbar
        del self.toolbar
        self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(self.action)
        self.iface.removePluginMenu('&ReKoTi Plugin', self.action) 
        del self.action
        del self.toolButton
        del self.popupMenu
```

But when I reload my Plugin, the `toolButton` won't get deleted and a new one gets generated. What can I do so the old Button gets delted aswell? I also tried to set the visibility to False, but this didn't work.

Comment: It doesn't look like you are actually removing it. The `addToolBarWidget()` method returns a `QAction` object, so assign the call to a variable e.g. `self.action2 = self.iface.addToolBarWidget(self.toolButton)` then in `unload()` method add the line: `self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(self.action2)`.

Comment: Thank you, Ben! I think I got confused by the function name. Works now :)

Comment: No problem. Glad it's working :-)